# Netstat -a command : Difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, netstat, ports

When running netstat -a on my local machine, i see ports on the 0.0.0.0 address listening.    I would assume that 0.0.0.0 is my local machine, except that i also see 127.0.0.1 listening to specific ports.

What is the 0.0.0.0 address?  What is the difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1?

Below is an example of the output:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            MyComputer1:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          MyComputer1:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          MyComputer1:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:6999         MyComputer1:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:6999         MyComputer1:49801      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:6999         MyComputer1:57172      TIME_WAIT
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Listening on `0.0.0.0` means that the program is listening on *all* IPv4 addresses assigned to the machine, whereas `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, only accessible from the same machine.

Comment: Sweet, didn't know that.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but what is a loopback address?

Comment: It's an address that loops back to the same machine it's on.