# Difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 in the context of the Firefox address bar

Tags: firefox, ip, firefox-extensions, localhost, loopback

I need to configure a [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) extension to load a page that can never exist.  It should be as fast as possible.  The obvious choice is `about:blank`, but the catch is that the API used by the extension requires the `http` protocol.  That appears to eliminate the possibility of using `about:blank`.

The obvious candidates are `http://0.0.0.0` and `http://127.0.0.1` (the latter of which is the loopback address, and should be the same as `http://localhost`).

***In this specific context***, what is the difference between using `http://0.0.0.0` and `http://127.0.0.1`?

What I've read so far (but none directly answer the question for this specific context):

- [What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)
- [Netstat -a command : Difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1](https://superuser.com/questions/240105/netstat-a-command-difference-between-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost
- http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3330.html

Comment: What makes you feel the answer(s) you've already read don't apply to your context?

Comment: I would not use `http://0.0.0.0` since `0.0.0.0` is not a routable IP address, so its technically not valid to use.  its only been recently that the browsers have started to special case `0.0.0.0` to mean the local machine.

Comment: @heavyd http://0.0.0.0 does the trick in Firefox. You cannot use http://127.0.0.1 as there may be a server running. OP wants to load a page that **can never exist**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In this context, what is the difference between http://0.0.0.0 and http://127.0.0.1?

> I need to configure a firefox extension to load a page that can never exist. It should be as fast as possible.

That rules out using http://127.0.0.1 as you cannot guarantee that a page will not exist (I'm running a server on local host for example).

There cannot be a server running on 0.0.0.0.

Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) gives us the answer.

http://0.0.0.0 is much faster regardless of whether there is a server running on 127.0.0.1 or not.

Case 1 - http://0.0.0.0:

[image]

[image]

Case 2 - http://127.0.0.1 (no server running):

[image]

[image]

Case 3 - http://127.0.0.1 (server running):

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  It's interesting to see that 0.0.0.0 is so much faster than 127.0.0.1, especially since 1.02 seconds is not enough time to wait for a full time-out for a server on 127.0.0.1.  Any ideas why?

Comment: In case 2 (127.0.0.1 no server, 1s) there is no full-time out to wait for ... I've added the breakdown of the timeline for case 1 and 2

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder how it differentiates between "no server on 127.0.0.1" and "server timing out".